# PHP: Using a variable inside a double quotes with backshlashes

Tags: php, curl, path

I have a variable with Windows path and backslahes. And in this i need two antoher variables. Looks like this:

```
$file_name_with_full_path = 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\upload\files\$filnr\$file';
```

At the end i need the variable $filnr and $file, but it is not possible to do it with " "

```
$file_name_with_full_path = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\upload\files\$filnr\$file";
```

With "  " i got an error, because in my script i do a curl-request.

How can i insert the variables with backslash in a single ' ?

my full script looks like this:

```
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    //schleife ausführen
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        //ip und filnr aus datenbank in var
        $ip = $row["ip"];
        $filnr = $row["filnr"];

        echo "$filnr $ip<br>";

        //filnr und dateiname momentan noch hart codiert
        $target_url = "http://10.74.20.94:6001/upload";
        $file_name_with_full_path = 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\upload\files\$filnr\$file';

        if (function_exists('curl_file_create')) {
            $cFile = curl_file_create($file_name_with_full_path);
          } else {
            $cFile = '@' . realpath($file_name_with_full_path);
          }

        $post = array('targetpath'=>'C:\bizstorecard\hossi','uploadfile'=> $cFile);

        $go = curl($target_url,$post);

    }
} else {
    echo "Fehler bei Abfrage";
}

function curl($target_url,$post) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: just use single quotes and concat? o.O

Comment: Of course it is possible … you just need to stop escaping the dollar sign.

Comment: @04FS He isn't even escaping it on purpose. On the other hand he isn't escaping the backslash!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use string concatenation instead:

```
$file_name_with_full_path = 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\upload\files\\' . $filnr . '\\' . $file;
```

Note you need to use `\\` for the `\` before the `'` otherwise PHP treats it as an escaped `'`.

If you want to use double quotes, you just need to escape all the backslashes that occur before something that can be interpreted as a variable (or a special character e.g. `\f` = Formfeed):

```
$file_name_with_full_path = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\upload\\files\\$filnr\\$file";
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/XndrK)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use variables directly in a single quoted string, if you want to use this you need to either concatenate manually or use [`sprintf`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

The reason the double quotes aren't working is because the backslash escapes the `$` character and so it just prints the string literally. You need to escape the backslash characters to print them correctly.

```
$file_name_with_full_path = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\upload\\files\\$filnr\\$file";
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, and with added readability, you can use curly braces inside double-quoted strings.

`$path = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\upload\files\{$filnr}\{$file}";`

Additionally, this works with array values addressed using single quotes:

`$path = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\upload\files\{$file['directory']}\{$file['name']}";`